# make orientation of an activity both landscape and portrait

Tags: android, android-activity

I want my activity to be landscape when device is horizontal and portrait when device is vertical. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml of your activity, when you define a new activity you must write`android:screenOrientation="unspecified"`:

```
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Or write nothing, because `unspecified` is the default value.

If you have to change orientation programmatically, you must write this:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Or

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

As the device has an accelerometer, you can easily switch between both

I hope this will help.